# How to track revenue's analytic to not have duplicate event in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity IAP, `ProcessPurchase` is triggered too if there is previous purchase.

My question is, if I put my revenue analytic in that function it will have duplicate data on dashboard. How do i make sure my tracking is setup properly ?.

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
{
    bool validPurchase = true;

    if (ReceiptSupport)
    {
        // Presume valid for platforms with no R.V.
        // Unity IAP's validation logic is only included on these platforms.

        #if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX

        //  Prepare the validator with the secrets we prepared in the Editor
        //      obfuscation window.

        var validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(), AppleTangle.Data(), Application.identifier);
        try
        {
            // On Google Play, result has a single product ID.
            // On Apple stores, receipts contain multiple products.

            var result = validator.Validate(args.purchasedProduct.receipt);

            // For informational purposes, we list the receipt(s)
            Debug.Log("Receipt is valid. Contents:");

            foreach (IPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in result)
            {
                //Debug.Log(productReceipt.productID);
                //Debug.Log(productReceipt.purchaseDate);
                //Debug.Log(productReceipt.transactionID);

                GooglePlayReceipt google = productReceipt as GooglePlayReceipt;
                if (null != google) {
                    // This is Google's Order ID.
                    // Note that it is null when testing in the sandbox
                    // because Google's sandbox does not provide Order IDs.
                    Debug.Log(google.productID);
                    Debug.Log(google.purchaseDate);
                    Debug.Log(google.purchaseToken);

                    if (google.purchaseState == GooglePurchaseState.Purchased)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("RECORD PURCHASE EVENT ANDROID");
                        Answers.LogPurchase (
                            args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedPrice,
                            args.purchasedProduct.metadata.isoCurrencyCode,
                            (result != null ? true : false),
                            args.purchasedProduct.metadata.localizedTitle,
                            args.purchasedProduct.definition.type.ToString(),
                            args.purchasedProduct.transactionID,
                            null
                        );
                    }

                }

                AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt apple = productReceipt as AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt;
                if (null != apple) {
                    Debug.Log(apple.originalTransactionIdentifier);
                    Debug.Log(apple.subscriptionExpirationDate);
                    Debug.Log(apple.cancellationDate);
                    Debug.Log(apple.quantity);

                    if (apple.originalPurchaseDate == apple.purchaseDate)
                        Debug.Log("RECORD PURCHASE EVENT IOS");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IAPSecurityException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Invalid receipt, not unlocking content. SUPER PROBLEM");
            validPurchase = false;
        }
        #endif
    }
```